# Partitioning an array based on a condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, callback

Using the array.filter function, I can efficiently pull out all elements that do or do not meet a condition:

```
let large = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter((x) => x > 10);
let small = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter((x) => !(x > 10));
```

However, in the example above, I'm iterating over the array twice and performing the same test each time. Is there a simple way to generate both 'large' and 'small' in a single pass over the array? In particular, if the callback to evaluate whether an element should be kept is expensive, I'd like to avoid calling it twice.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using TypeScript/ECMAScript 6 syntax it can be achieved this way. I am not sure whether it's more or less elegant compared to the original variant, but

1. It does the job;
2. Requires only one run;
3. **Can be further chained with `map ()` or other functions.**

---

```
const [small, large] =                             // Use "deconstruction" style assignment
  [12, 5, 8, 130, 44]
    .reduce((result, element) => {
      result[element <= 10 ? 0 : 1].push(element); // Determine and push to small/large arr
      return result;
    },
    [[], []]);                                     // Default small/large arrays are empty
```

---

More options can be found in [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860643/split-array-into-two-different-arrays-using-functional-javascript) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731072/dividing-an-array-by-filter-function) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151435/javascript-place-elements-that-dont-match-filter-predicate-into-seperate-array).

Answer (score 25):

Anything wrong with the naive ways?

```
let large = [];
let small = [];

array.forEach((x) => (x > 10 ? large : small).push(x));

// or
for(const x of array){
    (x > 10 ? large : small).push(x);
}
```

Comment: Why `map` instead of `forEach`?

Comment: @xehpuk you are right, forEach would be better here. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 15):

The existing answers do not seem to address the callback. One way to include it could be:

```
const partition = (ary, callback) =>
  ary.reduce((acc, e) => {
    acc[callback(e) ? 0 : 1].push(e)
    return acc
  }, [[], []])
```

and using it like:

```
let [large, small] = partition([12, 5, 8, 130, 44], (x => x > 10))
```

Comment: While I think calling a predicate in partition function a "callback" is a bit vague, it's actually a decent solution that you posted. 

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin nomenclature was from OP

Comment: Rereading it, I'm a bit surprised that I used the term "callback." In fact, I think the code that prompted me to ask this question involved an array of promises, so "callback" was a particularly inopportune way to describe the predicate.

Comment: Usually you'd go with `predicate` as the name.